# Buttons keeping their focus class after losing focus

Tags: extjs, focus, extjs4, blur, extjs4.1

I have some buttons in a bottom toolbar of a gridpanel that control adding, and removing records from the row-editing grid.

The handlers are pretty simple: "new" button creates an instance of the model, appends to the grid and then opens a row-editor on the new row; "edit" button just opens the selected row's row-editor; "remove" destroys the record from the store and refreshes the grid view.

For some reason these buttons don't lose the focus class that gives them a border when they have the focus. Here is a picture:

[image]

In the picture both the "New" button and the "Remove" button have the focus class, when I press the "Edit" button it also keeps the focus classes even after doing a complete row-edit operation and closing the row-editor.

I did find that when I mousedown on one of these permanently "focused" buttons and then mouseup away from it and then click something else the focus class goes away.

I know that I could put a blur handler for all button components in my respective controllers but I would have thought that this functionality was built in so I am asking to see if there is something I missed somewhere in the docs.

The classes that it won't let go of are these:

`x-focus x-btn-focus x-btn-default-toolbar-small-focus`

This is with ExtJS 4.1.0 in FF10 on Windows 7. But I did notice similar behavior in ExtJS 4.02 and 4.07, just haven't needed to handle it until now.

Comment: You do have `enableToggle: false`, right?

Comment: @sha nope not `enableToggle: false`

Comment: Add it then :) I think it should be default at least in 4.0.7 but I would try it anyway.

Comment: Hello ! I have a another problem. that is vice verse. I cannot understand why toolbars button could not be focused. Can give me advice where my errors are

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found out what it was:

At some point in the handler chain for each of these buttons the button gets disabled. When a button is disabled in ExtJS it prevents the `blur` event from firing.

It was necessary to disable the buttons so the solution to simply add `button.blur()` in the handler was the correct way to do go about it.