# Force Ext-Js 4 button to lose focus

Tags: extjs

Using Ext-Js 4.1.0

I have a very simple panel with just a single button. The button has a handler which makes an REST call using Ext.Ajax.request here is the similar code:

```
...
handler: function(button) {
   button.disable();
   Ext.Ajax.request({
      url: '/path/to/rest',
      method: 'POST',
      success: function() {
         button.enable();
         alert('Success!');
      },
      failure: function() {
         button.enable();
         alert('Failed!');
      }
   });
}
```

As you can see I disable the button and then enable when after success or failure. The problem is that now the button has focus and hence has the focus CSS class.

How do I "unfocus" the button so that it loses the focus CSS class and goes back to the way it looked originally prior to being selected?

Answer (score 3):

I had the [exact same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10690431/1062992). When a button is disabled it prevents the `blur` event from firing.

I needed to disable my button (like you) for my event so the simplest solution was to fire the `button.blur()` event manually somewhere in my handler chain.